# how to verify a date format in unix in a file?

Tags: shell, unix

I have a pipe separated file , how do i verify a field is in the format as : yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ

```
AAAA|BBBB|2016-03-01T00:00:00Z|DDDD|
```

Comment: Have you considered using perl script?

Comment: Does `grep -oE "[0-9]{4}-[01][0-9]-[0-3][0-9]T[0-9:]{8}Z"` help?

Answer (score 0):

Using awk:

```
$ awk -F\| '$3~/[0-9]{4}-[01][0-9]-[0-3][0-9]T[012][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]:[0-6][0-9]Z/' file
AAAA|BBBB|2016-03-01T00:00:00Z|DDDD|
```

Using `|` as field separator, if third field (`$3`)  matches given regex(`/.../`), print the record.

Answer (score -1):

This should help.

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ ! $1 ]; then
        echo Filename parameter expected
        exit
fi

let lineno=0

for i in `cat $1`
do
if [ ! `echo $i | awk -F\| '$3~/[0-9]{4}-[01][0-9]-[0-3][0-9]T[012][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]:[0-6][0-9]Z/'` ]; then
        echo "Not Matching Record found on line : $lineno :  [$i]"
fi
let lineno=$lineno+1
done
```

To Execute : 
`sh <script name> <filename>`

Comment: This permeates multiple problematic shell programming antipatterns; http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor and [useless use of backticks](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#backticks).